# ListBox with checkbox and image ( Disable/ Enable default selection behavior of ListBox )

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ListBox with Checkbox and an Image next to it.
In first phase :
Step 1: I would like to enable only the checkbox's for multiple image selection.
In Second phase :
Step 2: We would like to hide the checkbox's (Once they have done Step 1)
and do the next selection of single image by clicking on the image itself.

How should I proceed further ?

Below is the code so for:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="listboxImageDataTemplate">
        <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Visibility="Visible" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            Margin="3">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <CheckBox x:Name="selectCheckBox" Grid.Column="0"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding PatientImageId}" 
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.OnCheckedCommand,ElementName= filteredImagesListBox}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding PatientImageId}" 
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.OnUnCheckedCommand,ElementName= filteredImagesListBox}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </CheckBox>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">               
                <Label Content="{Binding ImageLabel}" Margin="2,4.7,52.017,102.5" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="10.667" FontWeight="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />        
                <Image  Margin="0,20,0,0" Source="{Binding ThumbNailImage}" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" />              
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
....
....
<ListBox Grid.Row="4" x:Name="filteredImagesListBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listboxImageDataTemplate}" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                                            Path=DataContext.CurrentVisitImageCollection}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                                            Path=DataContext.SelectedImageForMarking}">
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Do you really want to hide the CheckBox once it is checked ? The user then cannot uncheck it. Anyway you may want a trigger on the CheckBox Visibility property

Comment: I have a "Done Selection" button, clicking on it would transition the user to next step. Sorry should have mentioned it before.

Comment: OK. Add a trigger to the button, trigger the button's click event and make the checkbox go to the Hidden / Collapsed state.